# Замыкание и утечка памяти в Javascript

Tags: javascript, сборщик-мусора

Помогите разобраться с алгоритмом сборщика мусора.
Не могу найти статьи, в которых описывался бы подобный случай:

```
/**
* @param {ParentClass}
*/
function SomeClass(ParentClass){
    this.parent = ParentClass
}

function ParentClass(){
   this.child = new SomeClass(this)
}


var someObj = new ParentClass();
someObj = null /*эта операция приведет к утечке памяти, 
т.к. ссылка на someObj осталась внутри свойства someObj.child.parent */
```

**Верно ли утверждение в комментарии?**
Или же сборщик мусора поймет, что из window к созданному экземпляру нет доступа, и его можно убрать? Как мне это проверить?

Доп.:
*Не могу разобраться с вкладкой "Memory" в Chrome: на что смотреть, чтобы понять отработал ли сборщик мусора или нет?* Если есть актуальные статьи -- скиньте, плз. На хабре видел только устаревший пост о профилировании из 2012 года.

Comment: а вы думаете сборщик будет работать сразу как только вы ссылку удалили?

Comment: Нет, утверждение неверно. Только в старых браузерах была такая проблема.

Comment: @teran, да, думал, что сборщик сразу отработает после последней строчки кода. Но, очевидно, раз вы задали этот вопрос -- это не так. Есть ли более-менее точный способ понять, когда событие очистки произойдет? Условно, есть ли возможность наблюдать изменения?

Comment: К тому же, это не замыкание.

Comment: @Qwertiy, убрал тэг.

Comment: Сборщик мусора умный, и даже если есть перекрёстные ссылки, но нет ссылок на них из глобальной области видимости, или текущей точки выполнения, он удалит эти вхождения.

Comment: @Qwertiy именно такой проблемы даже в старых браузерах не было. Была проблема в IE в случае цикла через COM-объект.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Верно для старых движков js, сборщик мусора которых использовал алгоритм подсчета ссылок, вследствие чего циклические ссылки порождали ситуацию, когда сборщик мусора не освобождал объекты. С переходом на алгоритм mark-and-sweep утечка неактуальна. Подробнее см.: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management
2. Сборщики мусора задуманы и устроены так, что работают незаметно для пользователя, проводя очистку тогда, когда это нужно. Несмотря на то, что комьюнити предлагает разработчикам реализовать возможность отслеживания удаления объекта сборщиком мусора посредством событий, разработчики стандарта категорически против этого, т.к. это противоречит смыслу недетерминированной сборки мусора (https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues/238#issuecomment-116877193).